# how to set run my code with AsyncTask in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, mobile

how to set run my code with AsyncTask in Kotlin ??

- how to update text label in UI on script running and more description
- how I do in my projects to avoid memory leaks

---

```
 public fun zipAll(directory: String, zipFile: String) {
    val sourceFile = File(directory.toUri().path)
    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(zipFile))).use {
        it.use {
             zipFiles(it, sourceFile, "")
        }
    }
}
    private fun zipFiles(zipOut: ZipOutputStream, sourceFile: File, parentDirPath: String) {
    val data = ByteArray(2048)
    val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this!!)
    val textLabel = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView_progress)
    var i = 0
    sourceFile.listFiles()?.forEach { f ->
        i++
            FileInputStream(f).use { fi ->
                BufferedInputStream(fi).use { origin ->
                    val path = parentDirPath + File.separator + f.name
                    val entry = ZipEntry(path)
                    entry.time = f.lastModified()
                    entry.isDirectory
                    entry.size = f.length()
                    zipOut.putNextEntry(entry)
                    Log.i("listView ", "$i")
                    textLabel.setText("hello $i")
                    while (true) {
                        val readBytes = origin.read(data)
                        if (readBytes == -1) {
                            break
                        }
                        zipOut.write(data, 0, readBytes)
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Kotlin you should use [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=CjwKCAiAgJWABhArEiwAmNVTBw6HC1OoFBkIBqzvXmmh24ayhNjOM3XK_JXylCF1LGSQbnU00F47_RoC9UYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). They are the best option for multithreading in Kotlin. AsyncTask was used mainly in Java and is now deprecated, so you better not use it anymore.

For best practices against memory leaks and more info read [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4690472-memory-leaks-in-android).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Coroutines for the async task : [Kotlin Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=CjwKCAiAgJWABhArEiwAmNVTB2Rpc3prgUfnT-YW4pfKuY1g36VxsXmO_LL3wWJ6AzFy-x7eEMyOURoC7JgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)